# Java Neuroph Framework data format

Tags: java, networking, tcp, neural-network

I'm currently working on the java's neural network framework "neuroph" and I have a question regarding the types of the data in the data sets.

Is there anyway to use a data set that contains words and numbers as a training set? Because when I uploaded a data set with such criteria I am getting "NaN", which simply means the network is not receiving any data. I'm providing IP addresses in my data sets and types of protocols "UDP/TCP" as well as part of the data in the data set.

When I manually feed in a single line of data from my data set into the network to sort of analyze what the problem is, it gives me the error that the provided input is of invalid input format. So I'm wondering, is there a way to provide non-numerical values as input to my network?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: If you are using [DataSetRow](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/neuroph/core/data/DataSetRow.html), then no.
This class only accepts `double` as input.

You can, of course, implement your own class: `public class MyDataSet extends DataSetRow`, but you would still need to convert from *your datatype* to `double`.

If you are using IP address as input, why not break it in four numbers?
For example, the IP `1.2.3.4` would be the input `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

---

Do you know about Weka? (https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

This is an example dataset used with Weka: http://storm.cis.fordham.edu/~gweiss/data-mining/weka-data/soybean.arff

As you can see, it accepts Strings as input, and maybe can help you achieve your goal.

Comment: The thing is, I'm using the GUI for that framework. For that I will try your initial approach of breaking down the ip into 4 integers